# Is it possible to run asp.net and java web applications in the IIS server?

Tags: asp.net, tomcat, iis, webserver

I need to run the ASP.NET application and JAVA WEB application in a single web server. Because, These two apps are co-ordinate and work as a single application to the client end. Pls help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use url rewrite to make asp.net (IIS) as proxy server for specific mapping. For example:

```
  <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Reverse Proxy to webmail" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^example_endpoint/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8080/example_endpoint/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```